# Lambda functions getItem call in NodeJS is not printing any item in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Lambda function named "Test-Lambda-with-DynamoDB" as below. It fetches an item in DynamoDB having Key as "1". The code is as below.

The function executes and I see below console output

```
START RequestId: d121f379-066e-4883-a115-8bbc2c1ab80f Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: d121f379-066e-4883-a115-8bbc2c1ab80f
REPORT RequestId: d121f379-066e-4883-a115-8bbc2c1ab80f  Duration: 5153.66 ms    Billed Duration: 5154 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 86 MB  Init Duration: 138.01 ms
```

My Lambda functions (in NodeJS using SDK v2) code is as below --

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement

    var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

    // Set the region 
    AWS.config.update({region: 'ca-central-1'});

    // Create the DynamoDB service object
    var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

    // var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var table="whizlabcustomer";

    var params = {
        TableName: table,
        Key: {
            'ID': {S: '1'}
        }
    };

    ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log("Unable to read item. Error JSON: "+err);
        } else {
            console.log("Looks like a success!! ");
            console.log("GetItem succeeded: "+data.Item); 
        }
    });

};
```

I checked the CloudWatch metrics and did not observe any data point for Error count in the "Error count and success rate (%)" metric. I did not see any data points in "Async delivery failures".
Any directions or pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you aren't seeing either of your callbacks executed is because your lambda completes it's execution before the call to `getItem` completes.  As it's currently written, your lambda doesn't wait for the call to `getItem` to complete.

Instead of using callbacks, you can use Javascripts async/await keyword.  This will eliminate the need for callbacks and make sure your lambda waits for a response from `getItem` before exiting.
For example:

```
try {
    const data = await ddg.getItem(params).promise()
    console.log("Yay, I have my data!")
    console.log(data)
} catch (err) {
  // do something else
}
```

Nearly all of the AWS SDKs return promises, so you can use this technique when talking to DynamoDB, S3, etc.  Keep in mind that you'd use async/await instead of callbacks, never both.